# Running datadog and opentelemetry and datadog java agents gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, spring, open-telemetry, datadog, open-telemetry-datadog

I've been trying to run the datadog and opentelemetry and datadog java agents together.
The command that I'm using is

```
java -Xmx4096m -Xms4096m -XX:-UseAESIntrinsics -DdomainName=domain1 -javaagent:/tmp/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.logs.exporter=otlp -Dotel.semconv-stability.opt-in=http -Dotel.instrumentation.micrometer.base-time-unit=s -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://localhost:4317 -Dotel.exporter.otlp.protocol=grpc -Dotel.service.name=myapp -javaagent:/tmp/dd-java-agent.jar -Ddd.service.name=myapp -Ddd.service.mapping=jms:myapp -Ddd.trace.split-by-tags=aws.service myapp.jar
```

The app starts but after a few minutes I get the error

```
An unexpected error occurred in a scheduled task
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: datadog/trace/instrumentation/springscheduling/SpringSchedulingInstrumentation
```

When I run the app with just one agent (it doesn't matter which) it works.
There are no dependencies in the code of the jar

Run the app and not see that error

Comment: Hey Lior, could you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve here? What is the reason behind you deploying 2 agents in your java app?